# In Mac app signing process, how to apply the renew certificate?

Tags: macos, code-signing

I have a Mac app that already code signed using a valid certificate from Mac membership program. Now entering 2015, my Team Agent update the certificate. Upon entering "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles" section, I can see the Developer ID Installer and and Developer ID Application with expire date on year longer than previously. But the download button is disabled for this new certificate.

Do I have to revoke my old certificate? And, is it really necessary to code sign again our Mac app each year? ... that's going to be tiring...

Comment: Have you tried signing with Xcode? It can download certificates for you if your Apple ID is registered as being part of a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not revoke the old certificate. If you do this, any applications that you have previously signed with this certificate will be affected.

Only the Team Agent can download the Developer ID Certificates. As these certificates need to be carefully managed from a security point of view, I think it is Apple's view that they should not be available to all members of the team.

As a developer on a project, you can create (with the Keychain) and use your own certificate to use for signing and testing, but the Developer ID Certificate is likely to be used by either one member of the team, responsible for the final build, or added to the keychain of a build server.

Comment: That's it! I have done this process a year ago. And kind of forgotten what things went where. I will ask my Team Agent to download these certificates. Thanks!